# I want to hover my image and the button will slide from left and it is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please let me know why this hovering code is not working. I have a button that has an Id of myBtn that's what I styled in my css and it is still not working. I want to animate the button from 300 pixels to 23 pixels left.

```css
.button {
  background-color: #ffffff; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: rgb(2, 2, 2);
  padding: 10px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Arial Rounded MT;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  left: 300px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 3;
}
.Aljon:hover .button {
  left: 23px;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.container:hover .Aljon {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="Aljon"></div>
<div class="overlay">
<div class="content"><button id="myBtn" class="button"  href="">HIRE ME</button>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any confilct when it comes to div?

Comment: Hello friend. in html your button is indicated as `id = "myBtn"`, and in css as `#myBTn`. This is the mistake.

Comment: Hello friend thank you for correcting, however it is still didn't work.

Comment: My apology I am still a beginner? Can you explain further?

Comment: Thank you what should I put in ?

Comment: I've put my html code and showed me a lot of red stuff

Comment: Yes, I already fix that but it still the same

Comment: No I mean in my real code wait let me update it

Comment: By the way I updated the code regarding what you guys suggested me thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following is useful for you.

Please try replacing

`#myBTn {}`

with

`#myBtn {}`

Because your id name `myBtn`, not `myBTn`.

And try replacing

```
<div class="Aljon"></div>
```

with

```
<div class="Aljon">
  <button id="myBtn" class="button">HIRE ME</button>
</div>
```

Because you used `.Aljon:hover .button`.

Example here: https://codepen.io/yasgo/pen/wvzdgLG

Comment: Yes, I tried however for I don't what reason it is still not working for me hay. By the thank you for helping me.

Comment: By the way I updated the code regarding what you guys suggested me thanks!

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning you code, I got to this result:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="Aljon">
      <div class="overlay">
         <div class="content">
            <button id="myBtn" class="button" href="">HIRE ME</button>
         </div>
      </div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

On the CSS side, instead, replace

```
#myBTn {
   ...
}
```

with

```
.Aljon .button {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You mean I replace that on the Id myBtn or on to the hover one?

Comment: By the way I updated the code regarding what you guys suggested me thanks!

Comment: Mark this as the answer if it resolved your problem, please.